# Instruction error outside javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm making a form with a submit button to check login and a link to make a new user!

I'm coding this with:

```
<script language="javascript">

function new_user()
{
        document.getElementById("login").value='registo';
}


</script>

<form id="frmLogin" name="frmLogin" method="post" action="#">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Nome do utilizador</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Palavra-passe</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="OK" id="OK" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value="login"/></td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="new_user();document.frmLogin.submit();">Novo Utilizador</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to use a hidden field to know if the user pressed the button or the link.

To make the code smaller I'd like to use this code instead:

```
<form id="frmLogin" name="frmLogin" method="post" action="#">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Nome do utilizador</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Palavra-passe</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="OK" id="OK" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value="login"/></td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById("login").value='registo';document.frmLogin.submit();">Novo Utilizador</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Maybe because of the double-quote in your string that will terminate the `onclick` attribute early? What does the JavaScript console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having a quote clash in the definition of the `onclick` event handler. Your browser is interpreting it as `onclick="document.getElementById("`.

Try enclosing the argument of the `document.getElementById` sentence in single quotes.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('login').value='registo';document.frmLogin.submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as below

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('login').value = 'registo';document.frmLogin.submit();">Novo Utilizador</a></td>
```

use `single quote` for `getElementById` that will solve it.